# Does inline code keep the method [which wrote in it] in memory after finishing executing?

Tags: c#, .net, callback

Depending on what I know, when I define a method in C#, the local variables in this method will be released from memory after finishing executing the block of this method [when GC wants],

**but if I have an inline callback in a method, will these local variables be released from memory also ?**

In the following example, the [x] variable will keep its value after finishing executing the method and the message will show the value of [x] without problem although it's in a callback !!

```
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        int x = 1;
        System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        t.Elapsed += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show((x++).ToString()); ;
        t.Start();
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `x` is captured in a closure associated with the lambda function. This means that the value of `x` isn't actually stored on the stack associated with the exection of `MyMethod` but on the heap (in an object referenced from the lambda function).

The following example shows (roughly) how the C# compiler transforms the code:

```
class $$MyMethod$$Closure { 
  public int x;
  void Function(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    MessageBox.Show((x++).ToString());
  }
}

private void MyMethod() {
    var $$closure = new $$MyMethod$$Closure();
    $$closure.x = 1; 
    System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); 
    t.Elapsed += $$closure.LambdaFunction; 
    t.Start(); 
}
```

As you can see, the `x` variable is now stored in an heap-allocated object (called closure). The object will be alive as long as the timer can call the method (and as long as `x` can be accessed), but once you remove the timer, the closure will be also garbage collected.

It is worth noting that the compiler only *captures* those local variables that are actually used in the lambda function (so if you have some large data in the method, they won't be accidentally kept alive longer than needed).